# Ruby on Rails - basic form submission

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been working on PHP. Presently trying to learn Ruby on Rails. I am learning Rails online, for now I am badly stuck on Sign-up or can say a form submission page. Sorry if it's too silly.

Error is:

`undefined method new for nil:NilClass`

Here is the code:

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new   
    @user= User.new
  end

  def create
    @user.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
        flash[:notice]= "you signed up successfully"
        flash[:color]= "valid"
    else
        flash[:notice]= "failed"
        flash[:color]="invalid"
    end
    render "new"
  end
end
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<% page_title="Signup" %>
<div class="Sign_Form">
    <h1>Sign up</h1>
    <%= form_for(:user, :url => {:controller => 'users', :action => 'create'}) do |f| %>
    <p> Username:</br> <%= f.text_field :username%> </p>
    <p> Email:</br> <%= f.text_field :email%> </p>
    <p> Password:</br> <%= f.password_field :password%></p>
    <p> Password Confirmation:</br> <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation%> </p>
    <%= f.submit :Signup %>
  <% end %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <ul class="Signup_Errors">
    <% for message_error in @user.errors.full_messages %>
      <li>* <%= message_error %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :password
  EMAIL_REGEX = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i
  validates :username, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :length => { :in => 3..20 }
  validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true #:format => EMAIL_REGEX
  validates :password, `enter code here`:presence =>true #:confirmation => true #password_confirmation attr
  validates_length_of :password, :in => 6..20, :on => :create
end
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: @LuisMenjivar updated the question

Comment: @akash see the answer below `@user` is nil because you are trying to create a new object on `@user`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `@user.new(params[:user])` to `@user = User.new(params[:user])` I creates @user but it is not saved to database yet. On the line below `@user.save` that is when it gets saved. And remove `render new` because it will render the template with out setting the variables that the template needs. instead use `redirect_to :new` that will send the user to new and also set the variables needed

Answer (score 1):

In your **users_controller** > **create**, you put capital letter on `User` param.

For your case, it should be all lower case `params[:user]`. 
Side note, it actually depends on your attribute name you set on the form in the first place.

Edit:
In addition of that you should put `@user = User.new(params[:user])`

Answer (score 1):

First thing you should create new object of User class
Second pass correct params key

change first line in create method to

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])
```

So the changed code will look like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new   
    @user= User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
        flash[:notice]= "you signed up successfully"
        flash[:color]= "valid"
    else
        flash[:notice]= "failed"
        flash[:color]="invalid"
    end
    render "new"
  end
end
```

Comment: it gives 
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Comment: Use strong parameters
refer this http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to allow the `params` of `User` model in the `User` controller so as to avoid the `forbidden error message` as mentioned [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#saving-data-in-the-controller). Please note that this is Rails feature as mentioned

> Rails has several security features that help you write secure applications, and you're running into one of them now. This one is called **strong parameters**, which requires us to tell Rails exactly which parameters are allowed into our controller actions.

Thanks